# How do you separate the build flavors when selecting a build type?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have two flavor dimensions, staging and beta. I have two flavors apple and banana. Apple and Banana have different manifestHolder values which the app uses.

My problem is when I'm going to select a Build variant, it combines the two flavors.

[image]

Even though I've assigned them different dimensions.

```
productFlavors {
    apple {
        dimension "staging"
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "y",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }

    banana {
        dimension "beta"
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "x",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It combines the two because of the `dimension`.
You only need one dimension.

So let's say you have two `buildTypes`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

Then you do the following for `productFlavors`:

```
flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
    apple {
        dimension "default"
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "y",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }

    banana {
        dimension "default"
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "x",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
}
```

This will create 4 final build variants:

`appleDebug`
`appleRelease`
`bananaDebug`
`bananaRelease`